# Custom deployment with sbt

Tags: scala, deployment, sbt

I have a Scala application and i want to setup a deployment process result similar to one Akka sbt plugin gives, but i it requires project to be a microkernel. `Sbt-assembly` is a very cool plugin, but i want to have a free access to my config files, basically i want to have the following app structure:

```
/app/bin    - start script bash file
    /config - all my application .conf files
    /deploy - my project .jar with classes
    /lib    - all my dependencies .jar files
    /logs   - log files
```

I we checked typesafe `sbt-native-packager`, it's better, but it could place my `.conf` file and logs out of jars. All those settings in SBT looks confusing to me, what can i do to with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is not hard to update akka-sbt-plugin to make it work in general, add [this](https://gist.github.com/4lex1v/7868356) file to your `project` folder and somewhere in your build the following settings:

```
  .settings(Distribution.distSettings: _*)
  .settings(mappings in Compile in packageBin ~= { _.filter(!_._1.getName.endsWith(".conf")) })
```

The first line adds all dist settings to your project and the second one excludes all `.conf` files from your `.jar` and reads them from `config` folder.

Now you have to commands: `dist` - creates a folder with a structure you've discribed and `zipDist` which packs it all into `.zip` file, later you can add this to you publish setting:

```
addArtifact(Artifact(someName, "zip", "zip"), zipDist)
```